# sudo apt-get 'NOSPLIT Error'

Tags: apt

I just moved to a different country (Namibia to Netherlands) and for some reason sudo apt-get update stopped working and gets an error (I'm pretty new to Ubuntu)

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                                             
Get:3 http://na.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [4,618 B]         
Err:3 http://na.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:4 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease
Get:5 http://na.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [4,618 B]
Err:5 http://na.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:6 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Get:7 http://na.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [4,618 B]
Err:7 http://na.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Fetched 13.9 kB in 1s (8,095 B/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://na.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://na.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://na.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf` to your question.

Answer (score 5):

The domain that you are trying to connect to, http://na.archive.ubuntu.com, has expired. Choose a new download server in Software & Updates.

1. Search for *Software & Updates* in the Dash and open it.
2. In the **Software & Updates** window select Ubuntu Software tab -> after *Download from:* click the black triangle to show the dropdown menu -> from the dropdown menu click *Other*.
3. A new **Choose a Download Server** window will open, and in this window click the *Select Best Server* button.
4. Wait for Select Best Server to finish and click the Choose Server button. The best server that is selected will probably be a server in or near the country where you are located.
5. In the **Authenticate** window, authenticate with your user password.
6. You will see a window with a message that says *The information about available software is out-of-date*. Click the *Reload* button to update the available software cache.